# How to resolve intermittent deployment error on "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules"?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am adding `"AuthorizationRules"` on my ARM template where I am creating service bus, topics, and subscription. With these rules, I am running into intermittent build failures with `"MessagingGatewayConflict"` error and not sure how to resolve them. If I remove these rules, then templates works without any issues. Looks like racing situation among these rules.

If I do N deployments then eventually it goes away, but I do not want to make that practice.

**My Attempts:**

- I cannot use nested ARM template approach like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.servicebus/servicebus-create-authrule-namespace-and-queue/azuredeploy.json), because `"copy"` object doesn't work in it.
- I am trying to add following `dependsOn` like this, but getting error. I thought adding dependsOn per rule might help in this situation.

```
  {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcSend Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', 'IrcSend')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": [
          "Send"
        ]
      },
     "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]",
// getting error for below line.
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules', parameters('manageAuthorization'))]" 
      ]
    }
```

**Error:**

> Template validation failed: The template resource 'test-project-dev/IrcSend' at line '71' and column '5' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace.

**azure Error:**

[image]

[image]

**azuredeploy.json:** This is what I have currently.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "activeTopics": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": []
    },
    "activeSubscriptions": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": []
    },
    "resourceTags": {
      "type": "object"
    },
     "manageAuthorization": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of manage authorization rules"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    // ServiceBus Namespace
    {
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]",
      "comments": "testProject Service Bus Namespace configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "capacity": 1,
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    },

    // Authorization Polices
    {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcManage Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[parameters('manageAuthorization')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": [
          "Manage",
          "Listen",
          "Send"
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcSend Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', 'IrcSend')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": [
          "Send"
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcListen Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', 'IrcListen')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": [
          "Listen"
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
      ]
    },

    // Topics
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
      "comments": "[concat('testProject ', parameters('activeTopics')[copyIndex()], ' topic')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('activeTopics')[copyIndex()])]",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('activeTopics'))]",
        "name": "topiccopy"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P15D",
        "maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
        "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
        "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT30S",
        "enableBatchedOperations": false,
        "enablePartitioning": true
      },
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    },

    // subscriptions
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
      "comments": "[concat('testProject ', parameters('activeSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].topicName, ' topic ', parameters('activeSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].subscriptionName, ' subscriber')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('activeSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].topicName, '/', parameters('activeSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].subscriptionName)]",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('activeSubscriptions'))]",
        "name": "subcopy"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), parameters('activeSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].topicName)]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lockDuration": "PT1M",
        "requiresSession": true,
        "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P15D",
        "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": true,
        "deadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions": true,
        "maxDeliveryCount": 3,
        "enableBatchedOperations": false
      },
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceTags": {
      "value": {
        "Environment": "Dev"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "value": "test-project-dev"
    },
    "manageAuthorization": {
      "value": "test-project-dev/Manage"
    },
    "activeTopics": {
      "value": [
        "cart-submitted-events"
    ]
    },
    "activeSubscriptions": {
      "value": [
        {
          "topicName": "cart-submitted-events",
          "subscriptionName": "invoice-listener"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. Update `dependsOn`, like this:

```
"dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'IrcManage' )]"
      ]
```

Here is the full snippet for `// Authorization Polices`

```
{
      "comments": "Authorization IrcManage Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[parameters('manageAuthorization')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": [
          "Manage",
          "Listen",
          "Send"
        ],
     },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcSend Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', 'IrcSend')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": ["Send"],
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'IrcManage' )]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "comments": "Authorization IrcListen Configuration",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', 'IrcListen')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "rights": ["Listen"]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'IrcSend' )]"
      ]
    },
```